# How to detect in which direction the sprite is moving?

Tags: c#, xna

I'm making a 2D tower defense game for learning purposes, and now i'm stuck in how to make the enemies to look in the right direction when moving.

Here's what i tried without success:

```
    // Class constructor
    public AnimatedSprite(Texture2D texture, int lines, int columns, Vector2 position)
        : base ( texture, position)
    {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.position = position;
        Lines = lines; // How many lines the sprite-sheet have
        Columns = columns; How many columns the sprite-sheet have
        totalFrames = Lines * Columns;
    }
```

Here's the update method, it's a 5x4 sprite sheet:

```
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {

        // Depending on the direction the sprite is moving
        // it will use different parts of the sprite-sheet

        if (west == true)
        {
            initialFrame = 0;
            finalFrame = 4;
        }

        if (east == true)
        {
            initialFrame = 5;
            finalFrame = 9;
        }

        if (north == true)
        {
            initialFrame = 10;
            finalFrame = 14;
        }

        if (south == true)
        {
            initialFrame = 15;
            finalFrame = 19;
        }

        // When to update the current frame
        timeSinseLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        if (timeSinceLastFrame > milisecondsPerFrame)
        {
            timeSinceLastFrame -= milisecondsPerFrame;
            currentFrame++;

         // Reset the frame to complete the loop
            if (currentFrame == finalFrame)
                currentFrame = initialFrame;
        }
    }
```

In the draw method i try to detect the position the sprite is facing, I'm not sure the best way to do it but it's not working, the enemies are drawn correctly and animated but sometimes facing the wrong direction along the map path and at a certain point they disappear:

```
    public override void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        int width = texture.Width / Columns;
        int height = texture.Height / Lines;
        int line = (int)((float)currentFrame / (float)Columns);
        int column = currentFrame % Columns;

        Rectangle originRectangle = new Rectangle(width * column, height * line, width, height);
        Rectangle destinationRectangle = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, width, height);


        // Heres what i think it's not correct, how to detect the direction
        // I tried to calculate it by the last X and Y position
        // So if the current Y value is smaller the last Y value
        // The sprite moved south
        Rectangle lastPosition = originRectangle;
        Rectangle destinationPosition = destinationRectangle;

        if (lastPosition.Y < destinationPosition.Y)
        {
            north = true;
            south = false;
            east = false;
            west = false;
        }

        if (destinationRectangle.Y > lastPosition.Y)
        {
            north = false;
            south = true;
            east = false;
            west = false;
        }

        if (destinationRectangle.X > lastPosition.X)
        {
            north = false;
            south = false;
            east = true;
            west = false;
        }

        if (destinationRectangle.X < lastPosition.X)
        {
            north = false;
            south = false;
            east = false;
            west = true;
        }

        spriteBatch.Draw(texture, destinationRectangle, originRectangle, Color.White);

    }
}
}
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question here; and there is a *lot* of code (better than no code though!). Can you narrow down what is going on at all? Point out the line/section that isn't doing what you want based on a given input (provide the actual/expected output)?

Comment: If this code is everything related to this issue, then it seems that you will need to engineer the concept of character having a FacingDirection. There seems to be nothing related to that. Once you have engineered that, you can update your Draw method to manipulate images/drawings based on that data.

Comment: I updated the question with a few comments on the code to clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, i pick the position from the base class and update the last position in the base class as well, and in the enemy class the update method will handle the frames it will use depending on the position.

Enemy class update method:

```
            if (lastPosition.Y < position.Y)
            {
                initialFrame = 15;
                lastFrame = 19;
            }

            if (position.Y < lastPosition.Y)
            {
                initialFrame = 10;
                lastFrame = 14;
            }

            if (position.X > lastPosition.X)
            {
                initialFrame = 5;
                lastFrame = 9;
            }

            if (position.X < lastPosition.X)
            {
                initialFrame = 0;
                lastFrame = 4;
            }

            currentFrame = initialFrame;
            totalFrame = lastFrame;

            timeSinceLastFrame += gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
            if (timeSinceLastFrame > milisecondsPerFrame)
            {
                timeSinceLastFrame -= milisecondsPerFrame;
                currentFrame++;
                if (currentFrame == totalFrame)
                    currentFrame = 0;
            }       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In first look at thi segment of your code:

```
if (lastPosition.Y < destinationPosition.Y)
{
    north = true;
    south = false;
    east = false;
    west = false;
}

if (destinationRectangle.Y > lastPosition.Y)
{
    north = false;
    south = true;
    east = false;
    west = false;
}
```

The (lastPosition.Y < destinationPosition.Y) and the (destinationRectangle.Y > lastPosition.Y)
is same conditions, so your will have south = true in both situations.

Second, why are you using four boolean variables? Instead use one variable with four possible states. Enums is good for this:

```
enum Direction
{
    None = 0, // default
    North = 1,
    South = 2,
    East = 3,
    West = 4
}
```

And instead of four boolean use one Direction variable. Less variables is less troubles.

And last.
I'm not understand properly how are you moving your sprites? I mean how are you detect direction before changing coords?
In my opinion it should by like that:

1. In Update() detect in what direction you need to move and change Direction varialbe and basing on it change and update sprite state.
2. In Draw() anly draw sprite in current state.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I already solved it, and made it simpler i believe, without variables.